# List elements overlapping

Tags: html, css, list

I'm having troubles with my horizontal menu-bar list items overlapping.

So the `ul ul li` of the `nav div` elements overlap, what can I do to stop that?

[The jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DemonS/kbwtoad3/2/)

CSS:

```css
body, html{
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.nav {
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  color: #F5F5F5;
  background: #1565c0;
  display: flex;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0; 
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.nav ul, .nav ul li, .nav{
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #0d47a1;
}

.nav ul li{
  background: #1565c0;
  width:auto;
  position: relative;
  transition: background 250ms ease-in;
  line-height: 40px;
  display:block;
}

.nav ul li:hover{
  background: #0d47a1;
}

.nav ul ul{
  overflow:visible;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;  
  top: 100%; 
  width: 0%;
}

.nav ul ul li{
  border:none;
  display:block;
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  margin:0px;
}

.nav ul li:hover>ul{
  visibility: visible; 
}

.nav a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  margin: 0px 20px;
}

.nav ul ul li:last-child{
  border-bottom: 3px solid #0d47a1;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a>Hi there</a><ul><li><a>Here is the awesomeness</a></li>
    <li><a>Awesome</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kbwtoad3/4/) Here are some modification in your code:

```
.nav ul ul li {
    border: medium none;
    display: block;
    /*left: 0;*/
    margin: 0;
    /*position: absolute;*/
}
.nav ul ul {
    overflow: visible;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
    /*width: 0;*/
}
```

you can add below css not to wrap your text in 2 lines:

```
.nav ul ul {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kbwtoad3/3/)**

**CSS:**

```
.nav ul li > ul {
    position: relative;
    display:none;
}
.nav ul ul li {
    border:none;
    display:block;
    position: relative;
    left:0;
    margin:0px;
}
.nav ul li:hover>ul {
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body, html {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.nav {
    font-family:'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    color: #F5F5F5;
    background: #1565c0;
    display: flex;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
}
.nav ul, .nav ul li, .nav {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #0d47a1;
}
.nav ul li {
    background: #1565c0;
    width:auto;
    position: relative;
    transition: background 250ms ease-in;
    line-height: 40px;
    display:block;
}
.nav ul li:hover {
    background: #0d47a1;
}
.nav ul li > ul {
    position: relative;
    display:none;
}
.nav ul ul li {
    border:none;
    display:block;
    position: relative;
    left:0;
    margin:0px;
}
.nav ul li:hover>ul {
    display:block;
}
.nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    margin: 0px 20px;
}
.nav ul ul li:last-child {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #0d47a1;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a>Hi there</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a>Here is the awesomeness</a>

                </li>
                <li><a>Awesome</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: why you are using ul again inside of li.. Can please check the html tags ..may be it will help

Comment: if you look closer, it'a a dropdown menu, so it's a list in another list.

Comment: Well, yes it is, but the answer is already chosen. And you also didn't explain me what you did, so I learned nothin'.